# Use QGIS for collaboration on a Geopackage on Google Drive

Tags: qgis, geopackage, google-drive

We have a few peoples working on a small QGIS project using Geopackage as the main data storage. The GeoPackage is stored on a share Google drive. By working I mean reading for now but looking for posibility to write and update layers as well.

The current workflow is that only one person works on the Geopackage at any given time to avoid conflict.

I'm investigating possibility for several people working on Geopackage file at the same time. We don't expect that 2 people could edit on the same layers at the same time but it would be great if several peoples could work on different layers of the same GeoPackage at the same time, e.g. user1 updating layer 1, user2 updating layers 2.

Do you have any hints and experiences to share?

Comment: I would read https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html, chapter "6.0 How To Corrupt Your Database Files" and start thinking of other alternatives. SQLite database is a single file and it is not possible to have separate locks for individual tables.